# Java Dependency Management For Large Projects

Tags: java, dependencies

I hope I can keep this question specific enough, my team at work is currently debating the best way to manage our dependencies for a huge project (150+ dependencies ~300mb).

We have two main problems

- Keeping all the developers dependencies the same so we are compiling against the same files
- Ensure the project (once compiled) is comliped against the same dependencies

The two ideas that have been suggested are using a BirJar (all dependencies in one file) and just adding a version number to it and using a shared folder and pointing everyone's machines at the same place.

Or making including all the dependencies in the jar when we compile it (a jar, of jars, of jars) and just have a project that "has no dependencies"

Someone also mentioned setting up an internal version of Ivy and pointing all the code to pull dependencies from there.

What are the best practices regarding massive dependency management?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why don't you use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) and its [dependency management](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) ?

You can specify each dependency, its particular version and its scope (compile-time, for testing, for deployment etc.). You can provide a master `pom.xml` (the config file) that specifies these, and developers can override *if they need* (say, to evaluate new versions).

e.g. I specify a pom.xml that details the particular jars I require and their versions (or range). Dependent jars are determined/downloaded automatically. I can nominate which of these jars are used for compilation vs. deployment etc. If I use a centralised repository such as Nexus I can then build my artefact (e.g. a library) and deploy that into [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), and it'll become available for other developers to download in exactly the same manner as 3rd party libs etc.

Comment: Could you outline what it does? (perhaps in a 'story' or workflow?)

Comment: I've expanded on this and included a link to Maven (intro) and Nexus

Comment: This sounds great, thanks for the information! I'm doing further research info Maven and will report back to the team! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Incase you dont like/want to follow the Maven project structure...

If you already use Ant, then your best bet is to use Ivy for dependency management.

http://ant.apache.org/ivy/

It provides a rich set of ant tasks for dependency manipulation.

from : [Ant dependency management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091827/ant-dependency-management)