# Why does apache.commons.text.InterpolatorStringLookup lack a suitable constructor?

Tags: java, apache-commons

I'm trying to use `apache.commons.text` (v1.4).  I've installed its sole dependency, `apache.commons.lang3` (v3.7), which itself has no dependencies.

When I try to compile these packages, I get an error

```
[javac] /src/java/org/apache/commons/text/lookup/InterpolatorStringLookup.java:91: error: no suitable constructor found for InterpolatorStringLookup(HashMap<Object,Object>
,StringLookup,boolean)
    [javac]         this(new HashMap<>(), defaultStringLookup, true);
    [javac]         ^
    [javac]     constructor InterpolatorStringLookup.InterpolatorStringLookup(Map<String,StringLookup>,StringLookup,boolean) is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual argument HashMap<Object,Object> cannot be converted to Map<String,StringLookup> by method invocation conversion)
    [javac]     constructor InterpolatorStringLookup.InterpolatorStringLookup(StringLookup) is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac]     constructor InterpolatorStringLookup.<V>InterpolatorStringLookup(Map<String,V>) is not applicable
    [javac]       (cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac]     constructor InterpolatorStringLookup.InterpolatorStringLookup() is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac]   where V is a type-variable:
    [javac]     V extends Object declared in constructor <V>InterpolatorStringLookup(Map<String,V>)
```

Why does `InterpolatorStringLookup` lack a suitable constructor?

Answer (score 1):

All constructors of the `InterpolatorStringLookup` class have packaged visibility. To instantiate the class you have to use the method `interpolatorStringLookup()` in `StringLookupFactory`.

Comment: I still don't understand - I've written no code.  I'm compiling the packages exactly as received from their repo pages ([lang3](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) and [text](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/)).  Are the packages themselves written incorrectly?

Comment: Can you please specify which version of the library are you trying to build? And also how are you trying to do it (i.e: are you using maven)? You shouldn't need to add commons-lang3 by yourself. That should be on the project POM file already.

Comment: It's lang3 v3.7 and text v1.4, using Ant to build.  There is no POM file.

Comment: There's a pom file that you can see [here](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=commons-text.git;a=blob_plain;f=pom.xml;hb=ba44287bdd17a709523364820495760645da85b9). I suggest you to build it using maven instead of Ant.

Comment: I cannot change the project architecture.

Comment: Ok, based on your comment now I think your problem is that you're trying to build your own project with Ant and trying somehow to compile commons-text as a part of it. My next suggestion is to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091827/ant-dependency-management). It explains how to use Ivy or Maven in combination with Ant.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Do you think the problem is that Ant is not compiling the two packages in the correct order?